# in MomentJs, how do get quarter of the week in a month

Tags: momentjs

There is 4 or 5 weeks in a month. Using MomentJs, you can easily tell the number of [quarter](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/quarter/)

How do I come up with number like 1, 2, 3, 4 using MomentJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to ask, but **momentjs** supports the `quarter()` method. You can find the test [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/0b2dfcbe949f6ed4a7a17168dadcc560ffc54066/test/moment/quarter.js).

```
test.equal(moment([1985, 1,  4]).quarter(), 1, "Feb  4 1985 is Q1");
test.equal(moment([2029, 8, 18]).quarter(), 3, "Sep 18 2029 is Q3");
test.equal(moment([2013, 3, 24]).quarter(), 2, "Apr 24 2013 is Q2");
test.equal(moment([2015, 2,  5]).quarter(), 1, "Mar  5 2015 is Q1");
test.equal(moment([1970, 0,  2]).quarter(), 1, "Jan  2 1970 is Q1");
test.equal(moment([2001, 11, 12]).quarter(), 4, "Dec 12 2001 is Q4");
test.equal(moment([2000, 0,  2]).quarter(), 1, "Jan  2 2000 is Q1");
```

It also has the token `Q` that outputs:

> Quarter (1 - 4) -- sets the month to the first month in that quarter

You can see the docs for this.

---

If you want to know what week of the month it is, you can:

```
var weekOfMonth = Math.ceil(moment([2014, 8, 30]).date() / 7);
var weekOfMonth = Math.ceil(moment("2014-08-30").date() / 7);
```

Comment: that's for quarter of the year. how about the week?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul I'm not sure why you would want that but updated my answer.

Comment: yeah. I used for weekly inspection report. Once a week, record need to be taken. thanks